# Pythonで使用されるfor文の一行書きについて

Tags: python, python3

`for` 文が一行で書かれている例を見かけました。

```
for item in iterable: yield item
```

これは以下の記述と同様の書き方になるのでしょうか？

```
for item iterable:
    yield item
```

for文はこのようにして本来ならインデントしないといけない箇所を続けて一行で書けるのでしょうか？

コードは下記のサイトで出てきました。
[なんとなく理解するasyncio](https://note.crohaco.net/2019/python-asyncio/#future)

Comment: 丁度最近Qiitaの記事になっていました。[python3の構文TIPS](https://qiita.com/kamawanu/items/bb4b76346b013ecc7d27)

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても分かりやすい記事です。